# Pass a method as a function parameter

Tags: python, regex, methods, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass a method as a function parameter?

In learning regular expressions and how to use them, I decided to try and create a function I can just repeatedly call with the different regular expression methods that are used:

```
    def finder (regex, query, method):
        compiled = re.compile(regex)
        if compiled.method(query) is True:
            print "We have some sort of match!"
        else:
            print "We do not have a match..."
```

When I try it out, I get an atrribute error: '_sre.SRE_pattern' has no attribute 'method' even though I pass "search" as the 3rd parameter, which should be callable on compiled.  What am I doing incorrectly or not completely understanding here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `method` as a string, and use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def finder (regex, query, method):
    compiled = re.compile(regex)
    if getattr(compiled, method)(query):
        print "We have some sort of match!"
    else:
        print "We do not have a match..."

finder(regex, query, "search")
```

Also, use

```
if condition
```

instead of

```
if condition is True
```

because when `compiled.method(query)` finds a match, it returns a match object, not `True`.

Comment: Adding a default return value (third argument) for getattr() here might be useful, too. Just in case the string passed in doesn't match an attribute of `compiled`. Otherwise, `AttributeError`